# Spring Repository Library Implementation Problem

Tags: java, spring-data, junit5

I'm using Spring data JDBC library to implement my DAO. I"m very new to Spring Data Repository. Below is my error encounter.

```
@Repository
public class UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {}
```

**Error**: The type CrudRepository cannot be the superclass of UserRepository; a superclass must be a class

I'm using Spring Framework version 5.1.3 and spring-data-jdbc 1.0.3.

Comment: This library is not maintained any longer. You should seriously think of using plain Spring Data API.

Comment: https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jdbc

Comment: Can you provide a link or example on how to use this Spring-data-jdbc? It is very difficult to use the official documentation.

Comment: your `UserRepository` should be in `interface` not a `class`. That is also what the error is telling you.

Comment: If it is a interface, it contradict with Lorelorelore's answers but i have check the official doc that need to implement the method by ourself now.

Comment: There was an error in my answer, I've fixed it. `UserRepository` has to be an interface, not a class.

Answer (score 3):

The `CrudRepository` provides sophisticated CRUD functionality for the entity class that is being managed.

```
 public interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
        extends Repository<T, ID> {

    <S extends T> S save(S entity);
    T findOne(ID primaryKey);
    Iterable<T> findAll();
    Long count();                                                                                                                   
    void delete(T entity);                                                                                                  
    boolean exists(ID primaryKey)
}
```

- Saves the given entity.
- Returns the entity identified by the given id.
- Returns all entities.
- Returns the number of entities.
- Deletes the given entity.
- Indicates whether an entity with the given id exists.

Comment: How to implement the interface? Any concrete example?

Comment: This page will walk through Spring Boot CrudRepository example 
https://www.concretepage.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-crudrepository-example

Comment: **1public interface YourClassRepository extends CrudRepository<YourClass, Long>
**2Instantiate and Use CrudRepository
 @Autowired
 private YourClassRepository articleRepository;
 
**3Custom Repository Methods
 List<YourClass> findByTitleAndCategory(String title, String category);

    @Query("SELECT a FROM YourClassTable a WHERE a.title=:title and a.category=:category")

Comment: I"m understand your answers but I using this in selenium testng project. How to create the connection in Spring context (application.properties)? How to ask Spring to read my properties file and connect the database? It is easier in Spring boot but not in selenium testng project. What is your thought?

Comment: Is it require to use Classpathapplicationcontext or other approach? If yes, can provide an example?

Comment: Check this in spring site : https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/26/spring-mvc-test-with-webdriver

Comment: The Spring webdriver approach does not suit me because i'm using Selenium webdriver. What is your suggestion and example code?

Comment: How to integrate Spring Framework autowired function to any desktop/TestNG application?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple query to get all data from you database just use Spring `CrudRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

To get your data just use the method `findAll` already present in `CrudRepository`:

```
Iterable<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
```

Comment: How to customize a select query in case i want to select user by email address?

Comment: There is plenty of ways for doing this, you should take a look to the Spring Data tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: I try implement according to your mention doc but it display error. See my original post.